# Passing header along with res redirect without using query strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to set a header after redirecting to a particular route.

```
app.post('/signup', (req,res) => {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    req.method = 'get';
// console.log(req.body);
    user.save().then((doc) => {
        console.log("hi");
        return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
            res.header('x-auth',token);
            res.redirect('home.hbs');
        });
    })
});
```

I want to pass the token as a header without the use of query strings. How would it be possible?

Comment: you should do post

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP, a redirect response provides a URL for the user agent to request. It doesn't specify the rest of the request.

You can set a cookie though, if the redirect destination is in the same domain.

Comment: I am not quite able to do this. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: A cookie is a string that the user agent will copy from a response (from a `Set-Cookie` header) into subsequent requests to the same domain (as a `Cookie` header). The next request won't receive it as the `X-Auth` header, but at least it will still be in the request.